# How to calculate the difference between days in a table field

Tags: ms-access

Ok this *should* be a relatively easy thing to do, yet I'm at the head desk stage trying to figure out the insanity here.

I have a table called `tblPersonnel`.  I'm tracking two document expiration dates in date/time fields called `CED` and `PPED`.  When I run a query against `tblPersonnel` I need it to look at `PPED`, determine if that document is expired and if so use `CED` instead.  I have a few fields in the query that need to use this concept to determine what the output value is, but I am hitting a wall here trying to get the query to spit out the correct value.  Here's what I'm using for one of the fields - `Document Expiration Date: IIf([PPED]-Now()<0,[CED],[PPED])`.  What's happening is that the expression is constantly popping as false, so `PPED` is getting used regardless if it's an expired date or not.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

I've also tried to set this up as its own field in `tblPersonnel`, but that's even more aggravating.  If I try to set the field to just a text field - `IIf([PPED]-Now()<0,"Yes","No")`, the formula will accept the use of `Now()`, but it doesn't like the reference to the other fields in the table.  If I set it as a calcuated column, I can reference the other fields but it doesn't like `Now()`.  I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Do CED and PPED actually have time parts?

Comment: *determine if that document is expired*. What's the condition to check if a document has expired? Wouldn't be something like `[Ped]<=Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PPED is less than Date(), it is expired. Don't need to subtract. Assuming CED and PPED are just date parts, no time, consider:

`IIf([PPED] < Date(), [CED], [PPED])`

If PPED could be null:

`IIf(Nz([PPED],0) < Date(), [CED], [PPED])`

Comment: That definitely simplifies the expression.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally fixed it here.  I had another issue in that I wasn't accounting for how Access would handle a Null or blank value in `PPED`.  The functioning formula is `Document Expiration Date: IIf(Len([PPED])>0,IIf([PPED]<Date(),[CED],[PPED]),[CED])`  Thanks to June7 for helping me simplify the expression, as I was using `DateDiff('d',[PPED],Date())<0` but their answer is just so much cleaner and quicker to type.

Comment: I revised my answer.

Comment: @June7 well then, looks like I'm just going to have to flag that as the answer.